# Android Ormlite: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, ormlite

I am using ormlite in an Android project from Android Studio. I have configured Gradle to use it from Maven, like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
```

However, when I launch the app it's giving `NoClassDefFoundError` for all ormlite classes. The same works if it is done by copying the jars to "libs/" folder.

Any idea why adding them from Maven doesn't work?

Comment: What version of Android Studio/Android Gradle plugin is this?

Comment: Android Studio: 0.4.0, Gradle: 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this on **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    ...
}
```

The ormlite-core is a dependency that gradle will resolve by it's self. After editing, sync and rebuild you app, it should work.

If you want to put jar files in you libs folder, than your dependecies line from **build.gradle** will look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
}
```